# При нажатии на клавишу H функция работает не полностью

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Я сделал клавиши фортепиано в SVG, и к каждому `<rect>` подвязал событие `oncklick()`, и при нажатии на определённую клавишу на клавиатруе меняется заполнение `fill` на `orange` вместо белого или чёрного цвета. Вся клавиатура работает но именно 6-ая клавиша не перекрашивается в оранжевый цвет, но звук воспроизвоит. При клике на другие клавиши со всех остальных клавиш снимается эффект нажатия (просто перекрашиваются в белый цвет).

Так при нажатии клавиши (не клике мышкой), JS мне постоянно выводит ошибку `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` хотя все стили применяются и функции работают!

```js
var whiteNotes = document.querySelectorAll(".white"),
   blackNotes = document.querySelectorAll(".black");

var audio = new Audio();
// White sounds
function Do() {
   console.log("Do is pressed");
   audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558418994_noty-do.mp3";
   audio.currentTime += 0.4;
   audio.autoplay = true;
}

function Re() {
   console.log("Re is pressed");
   audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419037_re.mp3";
   audio.currentTime += 0.7;
   audio.autoplay = true;
}

function Mi() {
   console.log("Mi is pressed");
   audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419435_mi.mp3";
   audio.currentTime += 0.4;
   audio.autoplay = true;
}

function Fa() {
   console.log("Fa is pressed");
   audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419697_fa.mp3";
   audio.currentTime += 0.45;
   audio.autoplay = true;
}

function Sol() {
   console.log("Sol is pressed");
   audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419752_sol.mp3";
   audio.currentTime += 0.4;
   audio.autoplay = true;
}

function La() {
   console.log("La is pressed");
   audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419731_lja.mp3";
   audio.currentTime += 0.5;
   audio.autoplay = true;
}

function Si() {
   console.log("Si is pressed");
   audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419778_si.mp3";
   audio.currentTime += 0.45;
   audio.autoplay = true;
}

// Black sounds
function DoSharp() {
   console.log("Do(#), Re(♭) is pressed");
}

function ReSharp() {
   console.log("Re#, Mi(♭) is pressed");
}

function FaSharp() {
   console.log("Fa#, Sol(♭) is pressed");
}

function SolSharp() {
   console.log("Sol#, La(♭) is pressed");
}

function LaSharp() {
   console.log("La#, Si(♭) is pressed");
}

document.onkeydown = function (event) {
   if (event.key == "a" || event.key == "A") {
      Do();
      for (let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
         whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         whiteNotes[0].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
      }
   } else if (event.key == "s" || event.key == "S") {
      Re();
      for (let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
         whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         whiteNotes[1].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
      }
   } else if (event.key == "d" || event.key == "D") {
      Mi();
      for (let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
         whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         whiteNotes[2].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
      }
   } else if (event.key == "f" || event.key == "F") {
      Fa();
      for (let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
         whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         whiteNotes[3].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
      }
   } else if (event.key == "g" || event.key == "G") {
      Sol();
      for (let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
         whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         whiteNotes[4].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
      }
   } else if (event.key == "h" || event.key == "H") {
      La();
      for (let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
         whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         whiteNotes[5].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
      }
   } else if (event.key == "j" || event.key == "J") {
      Si();
      for (let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
         whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         whiteNotes[6].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
      }
   } else if (event.key == "w" || event.key == "W") {      
      DoSharp();
      for (let i = 0; i <= blackNotes.length; i++) {
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         blackNotes[0].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
          for(let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
             whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
          }
      }
   } else if (event.key == "e" || event.key == "E") {      
      ReSharp();
      for (let i = 0; i <= blackNotes.length; i++) {
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         blackNotes[1].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
          for(let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
             whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
          }
      }
   } else if (event.key == "t" || event.key == "T") {      
      FaSharp();
      for (let i = 0; i <= blackNotes.length; i++) {
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         blackNotes[2].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
          for(let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
             whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
          }
      }
   } else if (event.key == "y" || event.key == "Y") {      
      SolSharp();
      for (let i = 0; i <= blackNotes.length; i++) {
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         blackNotes[3].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
          for(let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
             whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
          }
      }
   } else if (event.key == "u" || event.key == "U") {      
      LaSharp();
      for (let i = 0; i <= blackNotes.length; i++) {
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
         blackNotes[4].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
          for(let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
             whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
          }
      }
   } else {
      for (let i = 0; i <= whiteNotes.length; i++) {
         whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
      }
      for (let i = 0; i <= blackNotes.length; i++) {
         blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
      }
   }
}
```

```css
.white {
   fill: white;
   stroke: black;
}

rect:active {
   fill: orange !important;
   stroke: black;
}

.small {
   color: gray;
   fill: gray;
   font-size: 14px;
}

text {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000px" height="120">
   
   <!--  Белые клавиши   -->
   <rect id="Do" onclick="Do();" class="white" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="5" y="105">A</text>
   <rect id="Re" onclick="Re();" class="white" x="23" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="30" y="105">S</text>
   <rect id="Mi" onclick="Mi();" class="white" x="46" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="52" y="105">D</text>
   <rect id="Fa" onclick="Fa();" class="white" x="69" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="76" y="105">F</text>
   <rect id="Sol" onclick="Sol();" class="white" x="92" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="99" y="105">G</text>
   <rect id="La" onclick="La();" class="white" x="115" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="122" y="105">H</text>
   <rect id="Si" onclick="Si();" class="white" x="138" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="145" y="105">J</text>
   <!--  Чёрные клавиши (с наслойкой на белые)  -->
   <rect class="black" x="14.33333" y="0" width="13" height="80"/>
   <text x="15" y="70" class="small">W</text>
   <rect class="black" x="41.66666" y="0" width="13" height="80"/>
   <text x="44" y="70" class="small">E</text>
   <rect class="black" x="82.25" y="0" width="13" height="80"/>
   <text x="84.5" y="70" class="small">T</text>
   <rect class="black" x="108.25" y="0" width="13" height="80"/>
   <text x="109.5" y="70" class="small">Y</text>
   <rect class="black" x="134.75" y="0" width="13" height="80"/>
   <text x="136" y="70" class="small">U</text>   
</svg>
```

Можете посмотреть на [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MrGregor_228/pen/eYpWXvb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var whiteNotes = document.querySelectorAll(".white"),
  blackNotes = document.querySelectorAll(".black");

var audio = new Audio();
// White sounds
function Do() {
  //console.log("Do is pressed");
  audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558418994_noty-do.mp3";
  audio.currentTime += 0.4;
  audio.autoplay = true;
}

function Re() {
  //console.log("Re is pressed");
  audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419037_re.mp3";
  audio.currentTime += 0.7;
  audio.autoplay = true;
}

function Mi() {
  //console.log("Mi is pressed");
  audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419435_mi.mp3";
  audio.currentTime += 0.4;
  audio.autoplay = true;
}

function Fa() {
  //console.log("Fa is pressed");
  audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419697_fa.mp3";
  audio.currentTime += 0.45;
  audio.autoplay = true;
}

function Sol() {
  //console.log("Sol is pressed");
  audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419752_sol.mp3";
  audio.currentTime += 0.4;
  audio.autoplay = true;
}

function La() {
  //console.log("La is pressed");
  audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419731_lja.mp3";
  audio.currentTime += 0.5;
  audio.autoplay = true;
}

function Si() {
  //console.log("Si is pressed");
  audio.src = "https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2019-05/1558419778_si.mp3";
  audio.currentTime += 0.45;
  audio.autoplay = true;
}

// Black sounds
function DoSharp() {
  //console.log("Do(#), Re(♭) is pressed");
}

function ReSharp() {
  //console.log("Re#, Mi(♭) is pressed");
}

function FaSharp() {
  //console.log("Fa#, Sol(♭) is pressed");
}

function SolSharp() {
  //console.log("Sol#, La(♭) is pressed");
}

function LaSharp() {
  //console.log("La#, Si(♭) is pressed");
}

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.key == "a" || event.key == "A") {
    Do();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    whiteNotes[0].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else if (event.key == "s" || event.key == "S") {
    Re();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    whiteNotes[1].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else if (event.key == "d" || event.key == "D") {
    Mi();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    whiteNotes[2].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else if (event.key == "f" || event.key == "F") {
    Fa();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    whiteNotes[3].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else if (event.key == "g" || event.key == "G") {
    Sol();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    whiteNotes[4].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else if (event.key == "h" || event.key == "H") {
    La();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    whiteNotes[5].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else if (event.key == "j" || event.key == "J") {
    Si();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    whiteNotes[6].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else if (event.key == "w" || event.key == "W") {
    DoSharp();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    blackNotes[0].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else if (event.key == "e" || event.key == "E") {
    ReSharp();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    blackNotes[1].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else if (event.key == "t" || event.key == "T") {
    FaSharp();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    blackNotes[2].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else if (event.key == "y" || event.key == "Y") {
    SolSharp();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    blackNotes[3].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else if (event.key == "u" || event.key == "U") {
    LaSharp();
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
    blackNotes[4].style.cssText = "fill: orange;";
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
      whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
      blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
    }
  }
}
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  for (let i = 0; i < whiteNotes.length; i++) {
    whiteNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: white;";
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < blackNotes.length; i++) {
    blackNotes[i].style.cssText = "fill: black;";
  }
}
```

```css
.white {
  fill: white;
  stroke: black;
}

rect:active {
  fill: orange !important;
  stroke: black;
}

.small {
  color: gray;
  fill: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
}

text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000px" height="120">
   
   <!--  Белые клавиши   -->
   <rect id="Do" onclick="Do();" class="white" x="0" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="5" y="105">A</text>
   <rect id="Re" onclick="Re();" class="white" x="23" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="30" y="105">S</text>
   <rect id="Mi" onclick="Mi();" class="white" x="46" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="52" y="105">D</text>
   <rect id="Fa" onclick="Fa();" class="white" x="69" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="76" y="105">F</text>
   <rect id="Sol" onclick="Sol();" class="white" x="92" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="99" y="105">G</text>
   <rect id="La" onclick="La();" class="white" x="115" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="122" y="105">H</text>
   <rect id="Si" onclick="Si();" class="white" x="138" y="0" width="23" height="120"/>
   <text x="145" y="105">J</text>
   <!--  Чёрные клавиши (с наслойкой на белые)  -->
   <rect class="black" x="14.33333" y="0" width="13" height="80"/>
   <text x="15" y="70" class="small">W</text>
   <rect class="black" x="41.66666" y="0" width="13" height="80"/>
   <text x="44" y="70" class="small">E</text>
   <rect class="black" x="82.25" y="0" width="13" height="80"/>
   <text x="84.5" y="70" class="small">T</text>
   <rect class="black" x="108.25" y="0" width="13" height="80"/>
   <text x="109.5" y="70" class="small">Y</text>
   <rect class="black" x="134.75" y="0" width="13" height="80"/>
   <text x="136" y="70" class="small">U</text>   
</svg>
```

Comment: чтобы меньше писать я бы перекрашивание обратно в белый выделил в отдельную функцию. Но чтобы было понятнее оставил код как был лишь поправив ошибки в циклах

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли =)